# How to reverse animation onScroll using Framer Motion(ReactJs)?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

If a text animation happening when on scroll(while in view) ,the text is coming from left then how to reverse it when it is not in view.
Like text will come from left when in view and again it will to to left when we scroll down or up.
I used reverse in Transition ,but I need it should triggered while in scroll.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.